Does dask worker heartbeat when loaded with tasks?
When dask workers have been assigned some tasks by schedulers, do the workers send heartbeats to scheduler or while performing tasks then don't heart beat. I am thinking that while working dask-workers don't heartbeat to the scheduler
I tried searching online, but didn't find much stating exactly about this. Also I checked documentation, did't find much related to this there as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
